# filter docker images with json output

Tags: docker, jq

Several requests.

I'd like to get json output from `docker images`, I can do by this way

```
$ docker images --format "{{json . }}" |jq .

{
  "Containers": "N/A",
  "CreatedAt": "2022-07-27 11:12:07 +1000 AEST",
  "CreatedSince": "8 days ago",
  "Digest": "<none>",
  "ID": "b673851840e8",
  "Repository": "python",
  "SharedSize": "N/A",
  "Size": "915MB",
  "Tag": "3.9",
  "UniqueSize": "N/A",
  "VirtualSize": "914.7MB"
}
{
  "Containers": "N/A",
  "CreatedAt": "2022-07-19 07:00:15 +1000 AEST",
  "CreatedSince": "2 weeks ago",
  "Digest": "<none>",
  "ID": "d7d3d98c851f",
  "Repository": "alpine",
  "SharedSize": "N/A",
  "Size": "5.53MB",
  "Tag": "latest",
  "UniqueSize": "N/A",
  "VirtualSize": "5.529MB"
}
```

then I want to get the iamge name with tag and ID

```
$ docker images --format "{{json . }}" |jq -r "[.Repository,.Tag,.ID]|@csv"
"python","3.9","b673851840e8"
"alpine","latest","d7d3d98c851f"
```

So my question is, how can I get the output as

```
python:3.9 b673851840e8
alpine:latest d7d3d98c851f
```

(optional) second request, how can I filter the output that only output the images with `*python*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `jq` to filter images based out of name, use the native `--format` flag itself

```bash
docker images --format "{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}} {{.ID}}"
```

(or) to filter names starting with `python`

```bash
docker images --filter=reference='python*' --format "{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}} {{.ID}}"
```

---

Using `jq`, collect the required fields into an array and use any of the string concatenation operators. You could also use `join("\t")` in place of `@tsv` to retain consistent usage of `join` method.

```bash
jq -r '[([.Repository, .Tag] | join(":")), .ID] | @tsv'
```

Comment: For the second request, the idea would be to use `select(..)` I'll leave it up to you for attempting that - https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#select(boolean_expression)

Comment: `jq -r 'select(.Repository =="python")'`, but how to get all with `*python*`?

Comment: the second command is better, thanks.

Comment: @Bill Look up `contains(..)`, `startswith(..)` and `test(..)` in the documentaiton

Comment: @Bill See update with a full fledged solution with docker options. Do accept the answer if it solved your problem